# The JavaScript Promise callback is executed before the Promise itself

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle-apex

At this moment I’m working on an Oracle APEX page, which contains the form for putting the parameters of the document. My aim is to refine the mechanism, which defines which fields of the form are available for users and which are not according to some information from the database.

I made the PL/SQL proceduces and wrote the JavaScript functions (as well as the AJAX processes) which help me to solve this task, but I have a problem when I need to execute some JavaScript code after defining the fields available for edit (for example, sometimes some report, which is bound with the form, should be refreshed or some auxiliary elements should be deleted from the HTML page). In other words, I have the function *enableFields* (which is executed when the parameters page loads), which must execute *enableFieldsBase* and then the callback function *callbackFunc* defined in the input parameter, but after some testing I discovered that the latter is executed **before** the former in spite of using the JavaScript Promises.

Here is the JavaScript function which makes the form fields available (or not available) using the information from the database:

```
function enableFieldsBase(){
    var page = 'P' + $v('pFlowStepId') + '_'; //define the page
    var docID = $v(page + 'DOC_ID'); //define the document

    //get the information which fields are available and which are not
    $.post('wwv_flow.show', 
      {'p_request'      : 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=DOC_ENABLE_FIELDS',
       'p_flow_id'      : $v('pFlowId'),
       'p_flow_step_id' : $v('pFlowStepId'),
       'p_instance'     : $v('pInstance'),
       'x01'            : docID},
    function(pData) {
      var res = eval('(' + pData+ ')');
      if (res.status == "OK") {
        //get the array of objects containing the shortened element names and the availability sign
        var props = res.data;
        //open or close the elements for edit
        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++){
          if (props[i].enabled == 1) apex.item(page + props[i].prop).enable();
          else apex.item(page + props[i].prop).disable();
        }
      } else {
         //…the code for catching the exceptions…
      }
    });
}
```

And this is the JavaScript function, which not only executes the previous one, but also takes into account the callback function:

```
function enableFields(callbackFunc){
  var page = 'P' + $v('pFlowStepId') + '_';
    
  //check if the variable callbackFunc is really a function
  if (callbackFunc != undefined && typeof(callbackFunc) != 'function'){
    //…the code for catching the exceptions…
  }
    
  if (callbackFunc != undefined){
    var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      enableFieldsBase();
      return resolve(true);
    });
    $.when(promise1).done(function(){
      callbackFunc();
    });
  } else {
    enableFieldsBase();
  }
}
```

So, my question is the following: what do I do wrong? Is it possible **not** to put the callback function explicitly into the code of *enableFieldsBase*?

I use Oracle 11g and Oracle APEX 4.2.6.00.03.

Comment: You have no way of knowing in `enableFields` when the work started in `enableFieldsBase` is finished. Without changing the API of `enableFieldsBase` to either: allow a callback to be passed; or return a promise, there's no way of doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you call `resolve` synchronously, without waiting for the post request to finish. So the promise resolves immediately.

Instead you should use the promise that `$.post` returns out of the box:

```
function enableFieldsBase(){
    var page = 'P' + $v('pFlowStepId') + '_'; //define the page
    var docID = $v(page + 'DOC_ID'); //define the document

    //make sure to RETURN the result of the `$.post` call, and chain a `then` method call
    return $.post('wwv_flow.show', 
      {'p_request'      : 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=DOC_ENABLE_FIELDS',
       'p_flow_id'      : $v('pFlowId'),
       'p_flow_step_id' : $v('pFlowStepId'),
       'p_instance'     : $v('pInstance'),
       'x01'            : docID}).then(function(pData) { // Use the `then` method
      var res = eval('(' + pData+ ')');
      if (res.status == "OK") {
        //get the array of objects containing the shortened element names and the availability sign
        var props = res.data;
        //open or close the elements for edit
        for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++){
          if (props[i].enabled == 1) apex.item(page + props[i].prop).enable();
          else apex.item(page + props[i].prop).disable();
        }
      } else {
         //…the code for catching the exceptions…
      }
    });
}
```

In the calling code:

```
if (callbackFunc != undefined){
    enableFieldsBase().then(callbackFunc);
} else {
    enableFieldsBase();
}
```

As jonrsharpe noted below in comments, if you pass to `then` an argument that is not callable (like `undefined`), it is like you didn't pass a callback at all. So you can further simplify to:

```
enableFieldsBase().then(callbackFunc);
```

It would be good though to drop the `callbackFunc` argument to `enableFields`, and just return the promise. The caller of `enableFields` should then decide themselves whether they want to chain a `then` call to it (or use `await`).

Comment: You can pass `undefined` to `.then` without any fuss, so I wouldn't bother with the conditional.

Comment: Indeed, @jonrsharpe, added to answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanations helped me to understand the JavaScript promises better (I've read articles on this theme before, but I couldn't find the proper solution of my problem), and also you gave me a great idea to make my code easier and clearer.